# Zero divisors of Z[i]

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

What are the zero divisors of $Z[i]$? I tried to find $z=a+bi$ and $w=c+di$, such that $zw=0$, with $z$ and $w$ nonzero, and found that $a=\pm b$ and $c=\pm d$, but it does not seem be right.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a subring of $\mathbb{C}$, which is a field, so it has no zero divisors (except $0$, of course).

Comment: Your calculations have shown that $a= \pm b$ and $c= \pm d$ is a neccessary condition for $zw=0$ but not a sufficient condition. Indeed the answers below show there is no sufficient condition.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 5):

If $zw = 0$ then
$$
0 = |zw| = |z||w|
$$
so ...

Answer (score 4):

The ring $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a subring of $\mathbb{C}$ and therefore it is a domain (like every subring of a field).

If you want to see it with computations, suppose $a+bi\ne0$ and $(a+bi)(x+yi)=0$. This is equivalent to
\begin{cases}
ax-by=0 \\[4px]
bx+ay=0
\end{cases}
The determinant of the matrix is
$$
\det\begin{bmatrix} a & -b \\ b & a\end{bmatrix}=a^2+b^2\ne0
$$
so the system has only the solution $x=y=0$.

Comment: Thank you! It answers my question!